# Aspectj default constructor pointcut

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj, pointcut

Im working with some AspectJ code and i want to catch all the executions for none private pointcuts.

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")//Public
public void publicMethod(){};
@Pointcut("execution(protected * *(..))"//Protected
public void protectedMethod(){}

@Pointcut("@annotation(mypackage.name.annotationName")
public void annotationPointcut(){}

@Around("annotationPointcut() && (protectedMethod() || publicMethod())")
public Object test(){ System.out.println("Should not print private"); }
```

I read about using ! (not) but could not get it to work. 
Something like

```
@Pointcut("!execution(private * *(..))"
```

But without getting it to work.

I could not find a modifier name for default class modifier in the aspectJ, have I missed it or do i need to try and solve it by using ! not sign in some sort of way?

Regards a new dev that are learning aspectJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to catch all non private methods.

```
@Pointcut("execution(!private * *(..))")
```

Comment: This is correct, but I want to add an explanation why `!execution(private * *(..))` is wrong: It means "intercept all joinpoints which are something else than private method executions". While this does intercept public, protected and package-local method executions, it also intercepts many more pointcuts, e.g. method calls (not the same as executions), constructor calls and executions, static and method constructor inintialisations, member get/set access and so forth. Thus, you get way too many hits. This is why *wheee* is right and *Nosfert* is not.

Comment: Sweet! It were all about where the ! sign should be! :)